# Npm React Scripts not working after MongoDB installation

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, npm, npm-scripts, react-scripts

I am working on a course React projects and working with the React dev server.

I was able to run **npm start** until I installed MongoDB local community server, not sure if it's related as I did not include any MongoDB in the project. I did some Google in the past 2 hours and found mixed answers and suggestions. I tried to uninstall MongoDB and remove its PATH variable but still did not solve the issue.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

This is the Npm error message I get:

```
Starting the development server...

events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:267:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)     
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:273:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn cmd',
  path: 'cmd',
  spawnargs: [ '/s', '/c', 'start', '""', '/b', '"http://localhost:3000/"' ]
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! burger-app@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the burger-app@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Roy\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-08-27T08_59_44_741Z-debug.log
```

This is the log output:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.6
3 info using node@v12.18.3
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle burger-app@0.1.0~prestart: burger-app@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle burger-app@0.1.0~start: burger-app@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle burger-app@0.1.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle burger-app@0.1.0~start: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;c:\Code\React\Course\burger-app\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\Roy\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Roy\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\bin;C:\Users\Roy\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle burger-app@0.1.0~start: CWD: c:\Code\React\Course\burger-app
10 silly lifecycle burger-app@0.1.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'react-scripts start' ]
11 silly lifecycle burger-app@0.1.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle burger-app@0.1.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: burger-app@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
14 verbose pkgid burger-app@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd c:\Code\React\Course\burger-app
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19041
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
18 verbose node v12.18.3
19 verbose npm  v6.14.6
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error burger-app@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the burger-app@0.1.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

This is my project's package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "burger-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

This is my system's PATH variables:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After TONS of Googling and reading, this what actually solved the issue:

The problem was that for some reason, the %systemRoot% variables were deleted from the Windows System Variables PATH variables.

Only after manually adding these variables back to the system's PATH variables, the issue was solved:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32
%SystemRoot%
%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem
%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\OpenSSH\
```